# Using field values from joined query as columns

Tags: mysql, one-to-many

I have two MySQL tables describing data that can be extended into subclasses, one that describes the parent class data and another one describing metadata fields as one-to-many relationships.

Example rows from table **page**:

```
id   | name
-----+-----------------------
123  | Example page
999  | Another page
```

Example rows from table **page_metadata**:

```
page_id | key        | value
--------+------------+----------------
123     | picture    | test.jpg
123     | video      | example.avi
123     | sound      | sound.mp3
999     | picture    | something.jpg
```

**Question:** Is there some way to fetch all this data in this format?

```
id   | name             | picture       | video       | sound
-----+------------------+---------------+-------------+------------------
123  | Example page     | test.jpg      | example.avi | sound.mp3
999  | Another page     | something.jpg | NULL        | NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT pm.page_id as id
  , p.name
  , max(IF(pm.key = 'picture', pm.value, null)) as picture
  , max(IF(pm.key = 'video', pm.value, null)) as video
  , max(IF(pm.key = 'sound', pm.value, null)) as sound
FROM page p
INNER JOIN page_metadata pm ON (p.id = pm.page_id)
GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: Yes, this is quite sufficient. I only changed `INNER` to `LEFT` to also include the pages that don't have any metadata attached to them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT page.id, page.name, picture.value, video.value, sound.value
FROM page
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT page_id, value FROM page_metadata WHERE key = 'picture') as picture
  ON page.id = picture.page_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT page_id, value FROM page_metadata WHERE key = 'video') as video
  ON page.id = video.page_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT page_id, value FROM page_metadata WHERE key = 'sound') as sound
  ON page.id = sound.page_id
```

should get what you need